# Вывод из двух таблиц с помощью explode

Tags: php, select, mysql

Добрый вечер.
У меня есть 2 таблицы.

Таблица Product

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
| id_product | name_product | size_product | color_product   |    
| 1          | Имя 1        | xl,l,m,d     | red,green,yellow|     
| 2          | Имя 2        | d,m,l,xl     | yellow,green,yellow|
```

Таблица Order

---

```
| id_order   | id_user      | id_product_order| option             |   
| 1          | 1            | 1,2             | xl, red, d, yellow |
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы на выходе у меня было вот так:

```
|Имя продукта | Размер | Цвет |    
-------------------------------   
Имя 1         | xl     | red   |    
Имя 2         | d      | yellow|
```

Вот что я делаю:

```
foreach($get_status_product as $item)
{
        $explode = explode(",", $item["id_order"]);

    foreach($explode as $item_explode)
        {

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id_product, name_product FROM product WHERE id_product = '$item_explode'");
            $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

                echo $myrow["name_product"];

        }

        $explode_one = explode(",", $item["option"]);

            foreach($explode_one as $i)
            {
                echo $i;
            }

}
```

На выходе у меня получается:

```
Имя1 Имя2 XL red XL Белый d yellow
```

Как мне это сделать в таблице как показано выше? Менять структуру базы данных и переписывать сотни строк кода не получится... Надо как-то именно таким способом сделать...

Comment: это видимо из области "join'ы - зло". ппц, убивать за такую структуру.

Comment: что находится в переменной $get_status_product?

Comment: Если там что то типа (select * from order), то зачем делать explode(",", $item["id_order"])?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо придется все таки менять структуру БД, потому что то что сейчас у тебя есть на столько убого, хуже могло быть только если бы у тебя таблица `order` состояла из двух столбцов и `options` включал бы в себя ещё<=`id_user, id_product_order`.

---

```
| id_order       | option                       |    
| 1&nbsp;        | 1 , 1,2 , xl, red, d, yellow |
```

Answer (score 0):

Прямого аналога `php explode` в `MySQL` на сколько мне известно нет. Думаю, нужно копать в сторону `LOCATE()` и `SUBSTRING()`. [Тут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) можно почитать про них и другие текстовые функции.